# rasberry pi 3 says it's hot (50*C), but is cool to the touch

Tags: pi-3, sensor, temperature

My raspberry pi 3 reports a [stable] temperature of 49.5 *C - which is pretty warm.  However, when I touch all of the components with my finger, including the CPU, it does not feel hot or even a little warm. I am confused, would have expected the CPU to feel warm/hot if truly running at this temperature.

Comment: What is the question? Does 49.5 *C should feeling hot?

Comment: 85° is hot. 50° is barely lukewarm.

Comment: If you were inside the package with the CPU chip itself, your question would be, "Why is it so hot in here?" If you're bored during this time of 'social isolation', look at it as an opportunity to learn about [heat transfer](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=physics+of+heat+transfer&ia=web)

Comment: Seamus' point is that the temperature of a component inside the SoC does not mean the entire thing is uniformly that temperature.  If that component is actually the hottest part, and only N% of the total mass of the object, located somewhere *inside* the object, and that hottest bit is 50 ℃, then it is probably not surprising that when your ~36 ℃ fingertip touches the outer housing, it doesn't feel like much.